# C# JSON request to WordPress

Tags: c#, json, wordpress

I need to get some data from a WordPress site using it's AJAX method. Here is the JS code that works:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://se-asia.ru/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
    dataType: 'JSON',
    data: { action: "getpermalink", id: 3887 },
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function (MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Now I need to create a C# code for it. Tried something like this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
string responseJson = webClient.UploadString("http://se-asia.ru/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", "{ action:\"getpermalink\", id:3887 }");
```

But always getting "0" as response, meaning WordPress can't determine the action I'm calling.

Comment: Are you sure it simply doesn't mean that you aren't allowed to call the action? You are not passing any credentials of any sort when calling the endpoint from C#, when doing it via jquery you are most probably already logged in and the browser appends your cookies with session data.

Comment: Try putting the action parameter name with single quotes: "{ action : 'getpermalink', id:3887}"

Comment: @Karl-JohanSjögren I tried his link with HTTP Requester (Firefox) and it return false when you make a post request with those params